# How do i store custom object in prisma schema?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, prisma

I have a model called "Setup"

```
model Setup {
  id String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId

  userId String? @unique @db.ObjectId
  user   User?   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])

  contract String[]
  legal    String[]

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

In this model i want to store an array like

```
const contractData = {
    id: '729a4839f3dapob44zt2b4b1',
    name: 'Example Name',
    text: 'Example Text'
}
```

so in my above model "Setup" i want to store the contractData

```
prisma.setup.create({
    data: {
      userId: '6399bc74426f71f2da6e316c',
      personal: [],
      contract: contractData,
      legal: []
    }
  })
```

Unfortunately, this not work.

How can i define an Object for contract and store this in my database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store a raw JSON, check out this guide: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/working-with-fields/working-with-json-fields

You will want to use the `Json` in Prisma in order to be able to store a raw JSON object (or multiple JSON objects as an array.)

```
model Setup {
  id String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId

  userId String? @unique @db.ObjectId
  user   User?   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])

  contract Json[]
  legal    String[]

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

Your Prisma `prisma.setup.create` query would basically be the exact same. Note that querying for what's in this JSON will be trickier - I would recommend creating a new model and then connecting it to the `Setup` model, but that if that isn't an option you can still perform some limited queries on the `contract` field.

Docs: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/working-with-fields/working-with-json-fields#filter-on-a-json-field

Answer (score 0):

In order to store an object in the contract field, you will need to change the type of the contract field from String[] to Object[].

```
model Setup {
  id String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId

  userId String? @unique @db.ObjectId
  user   User?   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])

  contract Object[]
  legal    String[]

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

store an object in the contract field like

```
prisma.setup.create({
  data: {
    userId: '6399bc74426f71f2da6e316c',
    personal: [],
    contract: [contractData],
    legal: []
  }
})
```

`contract` field is now an array, so you will need to pass the object as an element of the array, like `[contractData]`

Comment: It is not possible to change the type in schema.prisma to Object[].. i receive the following error message: error: Type "Object" is neither a built-in type, nor refers to another model, custom type, or enum.
  -->  schema.prisma:150.. should i install any extentions?

Answer (score 0):

this is old,

quick answer is, it will be best to create a new model for your contractData object and then link to the parent using Prisma's relation.

JSON would be extremely difficult to parse, and you can't just manufacture a data type like "object".

Lastly, [] is used to indicate a many relationship when suffixed to another model name, not to be confused with the List you have in Js or Ts